# Can I take small party decoration orders on H4 VISA

Tags: working, usa, h4-visa

My wife is on H4 VISA and is interested in doing ballon decoration for small birthday parties. Can she take such party decoration orders while on H 4 VISA.

Comment: Not unless she has an EAD. See https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/employment-authorization-certain-h-4-dependent-spouses  (I won't be able to turn this into an answer in the near future. If someone else wants to, please feel free)

Answer (score 1):

Individuals with an H-4 visa may work, but only after applying for, and being issued an [Employment Authorization Document (EAD/Form I-766)](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/employment-authorization-document).

[USCIS Employment Authorization for Certain H-4 Dependent Spouses](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/employment-authorization-certain-h-4-dependent-spouses)

> Certain H-4 dependent spouses of H-1B nonimmigrants can file [Form I-765, Application for Employment Authorization,](https://www.uscis.gov/node/41151) if the H-1B nonimmigrant:
>
> - Is the principal beneficiary of an approved [Form I-140, Immigrant Petition for Alien Worker](https://www.uscis.gov/node/41155); or
> - Has been granted H-1B status under sections 106(a) and (b) of the American Competitiveness in the Twenty-first Century Act of 2000 as amended by the 21st Century Department of Justice Appropriations Authorization Act (AC21).
>
> The Employment Authorization for Certain H-4 Dependent Spouses final rule (H-4 rule), effective on May 26, 2015, seeks to support the goals of attracting and retaining highly skilled foreign workers and minimizing the disruption to U.S. businesses resulting from H-1B nonimmigrants who choose not to remain in the United States and pursue LPR status.
>
> [For more information on the H-4 rule, please visit our Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/faqs-employment-authorization-certain-h-4-dependent-spouses) page.